# Get the Value from ChildWindow to UserControl Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight, childwindow

I need to get the Childwindow value to UserControl in silverlight Application.
I tried the below way , I get null value in Usercontrol page.

**ChildWindow**

```
public partial class QE : ChildWindow
{

        ATest ae= new ATest();
        public void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ae.Q = "TestValue";
            this.DialogResult = true;

        }
}
```

**Class**

```
public partial class ATest : UserControl
{
        public string Q { get; set; }

       public void asdf()
      {
           string checkvalue = Q.ToString();
      }    
}
```

I need to get the Child window's "TestValue" in UserControl page's checkvalue variable?How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Get the value From childwindow to Usercontrol Page,Do the Following way,

Using public property in App.xaml

It acts as declaring a static global variable in "App.xaml.cs" and using it from any part of the application.

Declare a public property in "App.xaml.cs"

public string MyName { get; set; }

Now we can access this "MyName" property from anywhere in the application using the "App.Current" object.

Code to set MyName value  in Page1.xaml

```
    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = App.Current as App;
        obj.MyName = "dpkshr";
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/frmMap.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Code to get MyName value in Page2.xaml

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = App.Current as App;
        MessageBox.Show(obj.MyName);
    }
```